# nvcc under linux complains: Contains a vector, which is not supported in device code

Tags: linux, cuda, nvcc

I have the following code

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #include <intrin.h>
#else
    #include <x86intrin.h>
#endif

//A bitset for the variable assignments
//The state for non existing variable 0 is stored as well, just to avoid +1/-1 adjustments
struct Atom_t {
    enum where { device, host};
    enum BoolOp {opXor, opOr, opAnd };
public:   //TODO make private later
    int VarCount;
    bool isValid;
    union {
        uint32_t raw[1]; //don't worry about alignment, the compiler will not use aligned read/writes anyway.}
        uint64_t raw64[1];
        __m256i avxraw[1];                                           
    };
public:
    __host__ __device__ friend bool operator==(const Atom_t& a, const Atom_t& b);
};

__host__ __device__ bool operator==(const Atom_t& a, const Atom_t& b) {
    const auto IntCount = a.IntCount();
    if (IntCount != b.IntCount()) { return false; }
#ifdef __CUDA_ARCH__
    __shared__ bool isDifferent;
    isDifferent = false;
    
    for (auto i = ThreadId(); i < IntCount; i += BlockDim()) {
        if (a.raw[i] != b.raw[i] || isDifferent) {
            isDifferent = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    syncthreads();
    return !isDifferent;
#else
    auto result = true;
    #ifdef _DEBUG
        for (auto i = 0; i < IntCount; i++) {
            if (a.raw[i] != b.raw[i]) { result = false; }
        }
    #endif
    auto AvxCount = a.Avx2Count();
    if (AvxCount != b.Avx2Count()) { if (result) { print("Atom_t == is incorrect"); } assert1(!result); return false; }
    for (auto i = 0; i < AvxCount; i++) {
        const auto packedCompare = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(a.avxraw[i], b.avxraw[i]);
        const auto bitmask = _mm256_movemask_epi8(packedCompare);
        if (bitmask != -1) { if (result) { print("Atom_t == is incorrect"); } assert1(!result); return false; }
    }
#endif
#ifndef __CUDA_ARCH__
    assert(result);
#endif
    return true;
}
```

The compiler complains

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
> "__nv_bool (const Atom_t &, const Atom_t &)" contains a vector, which is not supported in device code

However, the vector is **not** in device code, only in the host code. How do I make this error go away in NSight Eclipse Edition 9.1 running CUDA 11.

I tried:

```
#ifdef __CUDA_ARCH__
#  define DEAL_II_COMPILER_VECTORIZATION_LEVEL 0
#endif
```

But that does not work.

Comment: "However, the vector is not in device code, only in the host code."  The error is coming about due to this line: `__m256i avxraw[1];` which is visible in both the host code and device code compilation trajectory.  Your code does not compile for other reasons which makes it difficult to work with to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 3):

> However, the vector is not in device code, only in the host code.

The error is coming about due to this line:

```
__m256i avxraw[1];
```

which is visible in both the host code and device code compilation trajectory.

According to my testing this may be a possible workaround:

```
$ cat t32.cpp
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #include <intrin.h>
#else
    #include <x86intrin.h>
#endif
#include <iostream>
typedef char dummy[sizeof(__m256i)];

struct Atom_t {
    enum where { device, host};
    enum BoolOp {opXor, opOr, opAnd };
public:   //TODO make private later
    int VarCount;
    bool isValid;
    union {
        uint32_t raw[1]; 
        uint64_t raw64[1];
#ifndef FOO   //hide the vectorized datastruct from cuda's view
        __m256i avxraw[1];
#else
        alignas(32) dummy foo[1];
#endif
    };
};



int main(){
        std::cout << sizeof(__m256i) << std::endl;
        std::cout << sizeof(Atom_t) << std::endl;
}
$ g++ t32.cpp -o t32
$ ./t32
32
64
$ g++ t32.cpp -o t32 -DFOO
$ ./t32
32
64
```

(Fedora Core 29)

The `alignas(32)` directive is still probably somewhat fragile if the definition of `__m256i` changes dramatically.  And, clearly, the above is not CUDA code in the exact frame that was presented. It would need to be adapted (e.g. replace `#ifndef FOO` with `#ifndef __CUDA_ARCH__`)

I'm not suggesting that this code is correct, defect-free, or suitable for any particular purpose; it is mostly code provided by OP.  My objective here is to identify issues that I see and are asked about in the question, and suggest possible ways to address those issues.  Use this at your own risk.

Answer (score -2):

Found it!
The problem is not the code in the method, the problem is the presence of the `_m256i` within view of cuda.

The following patch fixes the issue:

```
struct Atom_t {
    enum where { device, host};
    enum BoolOp {opXor, opOr, opAnd };
public:   //TODO make private later
    int VarCount;
    bool isValid;
    union {
        uint32_t raw[1]; //don't worry about alignment, the compiler will not use aligned read/writes anyway.}
        uint64_t raw64[1];
#ifndef __CUDA_ARCH__   //hide the vectorized datastruct from cuda's view
        __m256i avxraw[1];
#endif
    };
```

Now that nvcc does not see the vectorized datatype it will stop worrying.

Comment: This solution has the potential (I believe) to make the structure a different size in the host code and device code compilation trajectories.    But if you're happy with that, great.  That's generally considered a bad thing in CUDA.  It strikes me as problematic.  `sizeof(__m256i)` is 32, so I would expect that to affect the size of the union and therefore the size of the struct.  I haven't fully verified that.  Since your posted code does not compile even apart from this issue, it makes it difficult to work with to suggest alternatives, or check things like this.

Comment: Confirmed.  The size of the struct is different between host and device compilation paths.  Use at your own risk.